# Why inspect element helps the element to be visible while running the selenium test?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Have you try to experience in Selenium2 that element is not visible even if it's not a hidden element? But when inspecting the element while running the test the element is visible and the test proceeds. What am I going to do with this?

```html
<input class="form-control chassis" placeholder="Chassis Prefix" name="chassisprefix" style="cursor: help;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="<h5 style=&quot;font-weight: bold;&quot;>Chassis Prefix</h5> If you already know the chassis prefix of the vehicle, please type it here. Entering the chassis prefix is one of the most effective ways of searching for a specific vehicle.">
```

Comment: Relevant _HTML_ and _code trials_ please

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.